# Brownian-like motion covering a set of positive measure

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, geometric-probability

I've been wondering about this question, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under what conditions does a Brownian-like motion $BL_t$ covers a set of positive measure or, what are the odds that, for some initial conditions and $\epsilon>0$, as $t\to\infty$ there is a chance that $BL_t$ covers a set of measure $\epsilon$.

Comment: What's your definition of a Brownian-like motion?

Comment: It could be Brownian motion indeed, or any similar kind of motion with some level of randomness.